# How to round current time in teradata and insert into timestamp(6) fields

Tags: date, teradata, rounding

I have a table  with date fields of `timestamp(6)` fields .

```
create table test_time 
(
  t1  timestamp(6)  format 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:si' ,
);
```

I want to insert into this table with current date and time rounded.
i.e. say for example if the current date time is  `08/07/2014 10:34:56` then  the value in the table should be  `08/07/2014 10:00:00` .
(or) if current data and time is  `08/07/2014 10:54:56`   then also the value should be
`08/07/2014 10:34:56`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example is truncating the time, not rounding.

Truncating can be done like this:

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) - 
EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)) * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE - 
EXTRACT(SECOND FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)) * INTERVAL '1' SECOND
```

But I don't get your second example, there's no truncation/rounding at all, it's simply subtracting 20 minutes?

Comment: Thank you . i have modified the second example  . the sql is workded

Answer (score 0):

```
select
cast('2059-02-19 10:59:59.110000' as timestamp(6)),  
CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM cast('2059-02-19 10:59:59.110000' as timestamp(6))) - 60   >= 0
THEN  cast('2059-02-19 10:59:59.110000' as timestamp(6)) + ((30 - EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM cast('2059-02-19 10:59:59.110000' as timestamp(6)))) * INTERVAL  '1' MINUTE) 
- (EXTRACT(SECOND FROM cast('2059-02-19 10:31:59.110000' as timestamp(6))) * INTERVAL '1' SECOND)
ELSE cast('2059-02-19 10:59:59.110000' as timestamp(6)) -  EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM cast('2059-02-19 10:59:59.110000' as timestamp(6)))  * INTERVAL  '1' MINUTE
 - (EXTRACT(SECOND FROM cast('2059-02-19 10:31:59.110000' as timestamp(6)))* INTERVAL '1' SECOND)    
END AS Converted_Time
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.